# calling setTimeout from a form with quotes

Tags: php, javascript, html

I have a html form for uploading a file, which is as follows:

```
$uploadhtml = htmlspecialchars(json_encode("<form action='up.php' method='post'
enctype='multipart/form-data'>
<label for='file'>Filename:</label>
<input type='file' name='file' id='file'/> 
<br />
<input type='hidden' name='pk' value='".$pk."'>
<input type='hidden' name='username' value='".$USERNAME."'>
<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit' onclick= />
</form>"), ENT_QUOTES);
```

I would like to  know if it is possible to call the s`etTimeout` function to update a particular layer, like follows:

```
onclick="setTimeout('updateLayer("text", "ff", "ok"))',1250);"
```

`updateLayer` takes 3 variables as arguments, how would I specify them as parameters within quotes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this:

```
onclick="setTimeout(function() { updateLayer('text', 'ff', 'ok'); } ),1250);"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also backslash the quotes. Note that this only works with " qoutes and not ' quotes in php, but works with both quotes in javascript:

```
onclick="setTimeout(function() { updateLayer(\"text\", \"your's\", \"ok\"); } ),1250);"
```